# Terraform - Count.index and String together

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

How do I append `count.index + 1` to a string? `"Subnet-"count.index+1` doesn't seem to work. I even tried quotes around it and still doesn't work.

```
resource "aws_subnet" "subnets" {
  count = length(var.azs)

  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block = element(var.subnet_cidr, count.index)

  tags = {
    Name = "Subnet-"count.index+1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can quote everything:

```
  tags = {
    Name = "Subnet-${count.index+1}"
  }
```

Comment: okay I thought `${something}` is desecrated and hence I was trying that without braces. Btw I updated the question, added a second question about the count. Can you update your answer?

Comment: @JohnDoe Do you get any errors when you do `var.subnets_names[count.index]`? It should be correct.

Comment: @JohnDoe Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what is the issue. Maybe [this](https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9#1254) will help you?

Comment: Nvm. I figured out about how the count works. Thanks for the answer.